# Xamarin forms ScrollView not working after dynamically added content

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hi My ScrollView is not working when I add buttons dynamically from the code behind. I add the buttons at runtime to a stack layout but because the size has not increased until the action happens on page load. It's not registering that there is enough content in the scroll view to cause the scroll to activate.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
 <ScrollView>
  <StackLayout >
        <Image Source="logo.png"></Image>
        <Label Text="Check In" FontSize="50" TextColor="White"></Label>
            <Label Text="Please selected a date to display sessions for." 
            TextColor="White"></Label>
       <local:DateTimePicker2 x:Name="dpSessionDate" TextColor="White" 
         PlaceHolderColorText="White" ></local:DateTimePicker2>

        <StackLayout x:Name="checkinButtons">
        </StackLayout>

       <Label x:Name="txtMessage"  FontSize="20" TextColor="White"></Label>
       <Entry x:Name="txtDayOfWeek" IsVisible="false" ></Entry>
 
       <syncfusion:SfButton IsVisible="false" Text="Goto Exercise" 
       x:Name="btnGotoExercise" Clicked="btnGotoExercise_Clicked" 
       BackgroundColor="Purple" TextColor="White"></syncfusion:SfButton>

 </StackLayout>
```

Here is how am adding the content.

```
public CheckInPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        api = new TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi();
        db = new ThehockeylABSqlLiteDB();
        txtMessage.Text = "Please select the name of the team you belong to ";            
        CheckInButtons();
        dpSessionDate.SelectedDateChanged+=DpSessionDate_SelectedDateChanged;
}
```

As you see am binding the buttons on page entry.

```
public async Task CheckInButtons()
{
    myList = api.GetAllSession().Where(w =>   w.IsActive == true).ToList();
    if (myList.Count == 0)
        txtMessage.Text = "This is no session data for the choosen date time " +
        dpSessionDate.SelectedDate.ToString();

    var test = DayNumber;
    ObservableCollection<Team> teams = await api.GetAllTeams();

    string name = string.Empty;
    checkinButtons.Children.Clear(); //just in case so you can call this code several times np..
    string teamName = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        if (item.TeamId == null)
        {
            teamName = "";

        }
        else
        {
            var team = teams.Where(w => w.Id == item.TeamId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (team!=null)
            {
                teamName = teams.Where(w => w.Id == item.TeamId).FirstOrDefault().Name;
            } else
                teamName="";

        }
        string sessionTime = item.StartDate.Value.ToShortTimeString();
        var btn = new Button()
        {

            AutomationId = PlayerId.ToString(),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            Text = item.Name + "\r\n" + teamName + "\r\n" + sessionTime,

        };

        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;
        btn.BindingContext = item; // add this here

        checkinButtons.Children.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because your method is `async` and you are not awaiting it?

Comment: You could however `await` this method inside of `OnAppearing` [calling-asynchronous-method-from-viewmodel-constructor-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057346/calling-asynchronous-method-from-viewmodel-constructor-xamarin-forms)

Comment: also consider using a bindable layout instead of creating all the UI manually

Comment: But how could I do that from the code then I dont understand @Jason Can you provide example link its used as part of a check in system so they need click first then more buttons get created.

Comment: read the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Comment: google `xamarin forms bindable layout example` for more useful links. Including videos.

Comment: Im still not sure how I would create the buttons dyanmically with that method can someone provide me an example as an answer please